# Python - getting text from html

Tags: python, html, text

How to extract text 'ROYAL PYTHON' from this html code in a nice way?
I've been looking for the solution for 4hours and I haven't found anything really relevant and working.

```
<div class="definicja"><a href="javascript: void(0);"
onclick="play('/mp3/1/81/c5ebfe33a08f776931d69857169f0442.mp3')"
class="ikona_sluchaj2"></a> <a href="/slownik/angielsko_polski/,royal+python">ROYAL
PYTHON</a></div>
```

Comment: I'd use BeautifulSoup. In other news, what are all those random right angle brackets doing in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

As Joel Cornett mentioned, using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="definicja"><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="play('/mp3/1/81/c5ebfe33a08f776931d69857169f0442.mp3')" class="ikona_sluchaj2"></a> <a href="/slownik/angielsko_polski/,royal+python">ROYAL PYTHON</a></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lxml and xpath:

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring

s = 'yourhtml'
h = fromstring(s)
print h.xpath('//div[@class="definicja"]/a[2]/text()')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a few things here: (1) The HTML snippet will always be valid XHTML, and (2) You're looking for the text within the second anchor tag in the snippet

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

htmlString = """<pre><div class="definicja"><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="play('/mp3/1/81/c5ebfe33a08f776931d69857169f0442.mp3')" class="ikona_sluchaj2"><img src="/images/ikona_sluchaj2.gif" alt=""/></a> <a href="/slownik/angielsko_polski/,royal+python">ROYAL PYTHON</a></div></pre>"""

xmlDoc = parseString(htmlString)
anchorNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
secondAnchorNode = anchorNodes[1]
textNode = secondAnchorNode.childNodes[0]

print textNode.nodeValue
```

xml is included with Python, so you won't have to worry about installing any packages.

Answer (score 0):

There also is the standard module xml.etree.ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

fragment = '''<pre>
<div class="definicja"><a href="javascript: void(0);"
  onclick="play('/mp3/1/81/c5ebfe33a08f776931d69857169f0442.mp3')"
  class="ikona_sluchaj2"><img src="/images/ikona_sluchaj2.gif" alt=""
  /></a> <a href="/slownik/angielsko_polski/,royal+python">ROYAL
  PYTHON</a></div>
</pre>'''

frg = ET.fromstring(fragment)
for a in frg.findall('div/a'):
    if a.text is not None:
        print a.text
        print '------'
        print ' '.join(a.text.split())  # all words to one line
```

It prints on my console

```
ROYAL
  PYTHON
------
ROYAL PYTHON
```